# Reopen Queue layout error on posts that were edited after closing

Tags: bug, review, design

Don't you think the red bar (indicating deleted text) is *tooooo* long?

> <sub>Click to show full image</sub>
>
> [image]

[See for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18911333) (the page where the screenshot was captured).

Comment: Doesn't happen on Microsoft Edge or (*shiver*) internet explorer. Would appear to be localized to Chrome (?)

Comment: I reproduced on Edge, and it looks even worse (though the worseness is likely because I have a high-DPI screen).